# Python Server send data not working

Tags: python, client-server

I am currently working on a server in Python, the problem I am facing is the client could not retrieve the sent data from server.

The code of the server is:

```
import sys
import socket
from threading import Thread

allClients=[]

class Client(Thread):

    def __init__(self,clientSocket):
                Thread.__init__(self)
                self.sockfd = clientSocket #socket client
                self.name = ""
                self.nickName = ""

    def newClientConnect(self):

      allClients.append(self.sockfd)
      while True:
            while True:
                try:
                    rm= self.sockfd.recv(1024)
                    print rm

                    try:
                        self.sockfd.sendall("\n Test text to check send.")
                        print "Data send successfull"
                        break


                    except socket.error, e:
                        print "Could not send data"

                    break

                except ValueError:
                       self.sockfd.send("\n Could not connect properly")


    def run(self):
                self.newClientConnect()
                self.sockfd.close() 
                while True:
                        buff = self.sockfd.recv(1024)

                        if buff.strip() == 'quit':
                            self.sockfd.close()
                            break # Exit when break
                        else:
                            self.sendAll(buff)
#Main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Server Connection to socket:
    IP = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 80
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

    print ("Server Started")
    try:
        serversocket.bind(('',5000))
    except ValueError,e:
        print e
    serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
        (clientSocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
        print 'New connection from ', address
        ct = Client(clientSocket)
        ct.start()

__all__ = ['allClients','Client']

#--
```

And the client connecting is:

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.4'    # The remote host
PORT = 5000              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', data#repr(data)
```

In need of a quick solution....
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested out your code, and when I commented out

```
rm= self.sockfd.recv(1024)
print rm
```

it worked fine. Basically the server stopped there to wait for a message that never came. If it still does not work for you, there might be two problems. Either you have a firewall that blocks the connection somehow, or you have old servers running in the background from previous tries that actually wasn't killed. Check your processes if pythonw.exe or equivalent is running when it shouldn't be, and kill it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jake, that worked but the text send as being sent continously how to just send one time only?

Comment: Glad it worked. Well, when you break after sending you only break the inner while loop. The outer will keep going. I'm not sure why you have to outer one anyway, if you remove it it should be fine.

Comment: Hi Jake, through the server code above can I get information about response code when I connect to it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that, elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

**Short solution**

Add a short `sleep` after `connect`.

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: One litle thing: `sleep` param expects seconds, not miliseconds. Maybe you mean `time.sleep(3)`

Comment: Its giving this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Simpl
eClinet.py", line 8, in <module>
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
ailed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

To wait for response:

```
with s.makefile('rb') as f:
     data = f.read() # block until the whole response is read
s.close()
```

There are multiple issues in your code:

- nested `while True` without break
- `finally: ..close()` is executed *before* `except ValueError: ..send`
- multiple `self.sockfd.close()`
- etc

Also you should probably use `.sendall()` instead of `.send()`.

Comment: ok a short edit, client is connecting but waiting endlessly for the data.

Comment: @Ali: the server waits for data from the client.

Comment: ok, so can we remove this waiting so the server just sends the data.

Comment: @Ali: read your code: if the client uses `.recv()` to read data from the server; what method might the server use to read data from the client?  Also remove outer `while True`.

Answer (score 0):

your server code is excepting client send something first,

```
rm= self.sockfd.recv(1024)
```

but I don't see any in your code

please try send something in your client code

```
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("hello")
```

Comment: yeah these lines show who has connected only; and working fine.

Comment: Even when I access my server from browser, it keeps on waiting

Comment: Thanks I commented out this line for receiving data and now problem solved as pointed out by Jake above.